# Oracle CLOB column value replace with something

Tags: oracle, replace, clob

In my Oracle table, I have a column 'DISPLAY_TEXT' of type CLOB.
The value in that :

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en-us"><head</head><body>   <!--#include virtual="/demo/pages/my_new_page_basic.txt"-->"

I want to replace, my_new_page_basic.txt with my_new_page_demo.txt
```

How can we achieve.

Comment: You don't say what version of Oracle. Since 11g, you can use the REPLACE function on CLOB values.

Comment: we are using 11g. Thanks

Comment: Basically I want to update the table with the new column, I think CLOB REPLACE working only on SELECT

Comment: No, REPLACE does not work only on SELECT.  It is simply a function that returns a value and can be used anywhere you need to specify a value. `UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, ...)` is the basic structure you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table t ( x clob );

create or replace
 procedure lob_replace( p_lob in out clob,
 p_what in varchar2,
 p_with in varchar2 )
 as
 n number;
 begin
 n := dbms_lob.instr( p_lob, p_what );
 if ( nvl(n,0) > 0 )
 then
 dbms_lob.copy( p_lob,
 p_lob,
dbms_lob.getlength(p_lob),
 n+length(p_with),
 n+length(p_what) );

 dbms_lob.write( p_lob, length(p_with), n, p_with );
 if ( length(p_what) > length(p_with) )
 then
dbms_lob.trim( p_lob,
 dbms_lob.getlength(p_lob)-(length(p_what)-length(p_with)) );
 end if;
 end if;
 end;
/

 insert into t values ( 'my_new_page_basic.txt' )

begin
 for x in ( select * from t ) loop 
 lob_replace( x.x, 'my_new_page_basic.txt','my_new_page_demo.txt' );
 end loop;
 end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way we can achieve with SQL instead of PROC.

Comment: This is PLSQL using a function